# YII2 How to add custom validation rule for file type

Tags: file, validation, yii2

I am using :

```
[['avatar'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'message'=>'png,jpg,jpeg files only', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg ,jpeg','on'=>'update']
```

It shows me validation message : "Only files with these extensions are allowed: png, jpg, jpeg."
But i want validation message like: "png,jpg,jpeg files only".
How can i do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [wrongExtension](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-filevalidator.html#$wrongExtension-detail) property:

```
[['avatar'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg ,jpeg', 'wrongExtension'=>'{extensions} files only', 'on'=>'update']
```